# How to start and stop virtualbox machines, only from CLI via ssh?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, opensuse

I have a server that I want to run virtual machines on

I want to use virtualbox but I want to start and stop them using only ssh as the server is headless.

The question:
How to start and stop virtualbox machines, only from CLI via ssh?
And what are the command or where to get info on commands?

Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: If you are set up (via SSH) to run things on your server, then you can run VBOX and start the machines.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to start and stop virtualbox machines, only from CLI via ssh...sorry

Comment: Googling for "virtualbox commandline" has e.g. [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) as second hit. RTFM?

Comment: Use use VBoxManage startvm to start from command line. Your question really has nothing to to do with SSH or other machines

Comment: And what are the command or where to get info on commands?   ... Your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a VBOX virtual machine by Command Line using the command line structure:  vboxmanage

[VBOX command line](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/11/10/intro-to-vbox-cli/)

> To list all the registered VMs, simply run vboxmanage list vms. Note
> that if you are using Vagrant with VirtualBox, this command will also
> show VirtualBox VMs that have been instantiated by Vagrant. Similarly,
> if you are using Docker Machine with VirtualBox, this command will
> show you VMs created by Docker Machine

.

> To list all the running VMs, use vboxmanage list runningvms

.

> To start a VM, run vboxmanage startvm . You can
> optionally specify a --type parameter to control how the VM is
> started. Using --type gui will show it via the host GUI; using --type
> headless means you’ll need to interact over the network (typically via
> SSH). To emulate Vagrant/Docker Machine-like behavior, you’d use
> --type headless.